# Run IntegrationFlow after another

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have two IntegrationFlows for importing Head and Position Data.
For importing I use csv-Files, which are organized in a folder structure. The Head-CSV-Files, are in the Head-Folder and die Position-Files in the Position-Folder.
The structure of the csv-Files is of course different.

Now it is necessary, that the Head-Data are getting imported before the Position Data. But when no Head Data available, the Position-Folder should be processed anyway. (E.g. for an Position Update of an existing Head)

Currently I have two IntegrationFlows. One for each case.

Is there a possibility to call this Integrationflows one after another? If not, is there any possibility (maybe over the aggregation method), to use two different MessageSources by one IntegrationFlow, with the possibility to detect if it is an Head or an Position and the safety, that the Head-Message-Source is proceeded bevore the Position?

```
@Configuration
public class MyHeadFlowConfig    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow myHeadFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(myHeadMessageSource, myPollerConsumer))
                .filter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv"))
                .handle(myHeadJobConfig)
                .get();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class MyPositionFlowConfig    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow myPositionFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(myPositionMessageSource, myPollerConsumer))
                .filter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv"))
                .handle(myPositionJobConfig)
                .get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can accomplish this.

If the two integration flows are running in the same JVM, the simplest and the most natural approach would be to share a *channel* . Basically create an instance of `MessageChannel` and wire it at the end of one floe and the beginning of another.

```
floaA -> sharedChannel -> flowB
```

[ApplicationEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/applicationevent.html) support would be another approach. 
And of course bunch of provided Inbound/Outbound adapters.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand it right, I should after the .handle(job) do a .channel("myMessageChannel") and the second IntegrationFlow should be initialized by this Channel, right? But how can I give the secondIntegrationFlow then a new MessageSource with the Positiondata? Or do I missunderstand your answer? Could you maybe add a small Code example?

Comment: Integration flow could have many sources. That is one of the main advantages of having _channel_ abstraction. For examples let's presume we call this channel _flowBridgeChannel_. Now, `FlowA` upon finishing sends message to this channel essentially initiating `FlowB`. In addition to be initiated by the `FlowA`, `FlowB` can have additional MessageSource(es) that will send message to the same _flowBridgeChannel_. In other words _flowBridgeChannel_ can be fed by many sources, yet everything downstream stays the same.

Comment: In theory, I think i understand how to do...but I can't get it to work...you say FlowB can have additional Message Source(s)  that send message to the channel. But how can I add these Message Source(s) in FlowB. And how can I be sure, that only the message from floatA to the sharedChannel would activate flowB.
Sorry if my questions are a little bit basic...but it seems i have not understand the flow and channel functionality completly